# Touch listener on multiple Textviews?

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener

```
private TextView tv2;

tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());

public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Hauteur.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 80);
                    Hauteur.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(recuperationJson.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Action you you want on finger up
                    Hauteur.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 60);

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hi ! I would like to the same Motion Event (same actions) on 5 other Textview's, so i have to create 5 others public class CustomTouchListener1,2,3,4,5 ...  or there's a way to group them all ?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, i chosed Mushahid Khatri solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make Custom Touch Listner.

You can achieve it by following code

```
private TextView tv2,tv1;

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv2.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);



    View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {




            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Hauteur.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 80);
                    Hauteur.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(recuperationJson.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));

                    //Here if you want to know from wich touch this event has accured you can do following code
                    switch (v.getId()){
                        case R.id.textView1:
                            break;
                        case R.id.textView2:
                            break;
                        case R.id.textView3:
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Action you you want on finger up
                    Hauteur.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 60);

                    switch (v.getId()){
                        case R.id.textView1:
                            break;
                        case R.id.textView2:
                            break;
                        case R.id.textView3:
                            break;
                    }


                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
```

Hope work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use RecycleView or ListView instead of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Rather creating Inner class, create anonymous class and set it directly on `View`.

```
private final View.OnTouchListener myTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To set on `TextView`.

```
tv2.setOnTouchListener(myTouchListener)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Create an anonymous class

```
private final View.OnTouchListener myTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now set this touch event to your required textviews

```
private TextView tv1,tv2.tv3,tv4,tv5;
tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
```

Now set the touch event

```
tv1.setOnTouchListener(myTouchListener);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(myTouchListener);
tv3.setOnTouchListener(myTouchListener);
tv4.setOnTouchListener(myTouchListener);
tv5.setOnTouchListener(myTouchListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

add your `TextViews` to list and pass it to `setListnerOnTextViews`

```
private function setListnerOnTextViews(List<TextView> tvs){
   for(int i =0; i<tvs.size;i++){
     if(tvs.get(0) instance of TextView){
       tvs.get(0).setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());
     }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same OnTouchListener for several TextView, you don't need create another class

```
        private TextView tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        tv2.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        tv3.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        tv4.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        tv5.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```